# Partial Derivative of Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I can't follow a step in one of my textbooks... It says that given a function $f(x-vt)$, we know that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{v} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$. I think this comes from the chain rule but I can't figure out how to make that connection. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Write $z = x - vt$, and think of $z$ as a function of two variables.

Comment: The chain-rule says that: $\frac{\partial f(A)}{\partial B} = \left(\frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y}\right)_{y=A} \frac{\partial A}{\partial B}$. Use this with the hint above and with both $A=x$ and $A=t$ and compare.

Comment: Your textbook is using very sloppy notation! It would be true if $f(x,t)=g(x-vt)$ for some differentiable function $g$ of *one* variable, though.